# Beginner question custom google assistant action

Tags: google-apps-script, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

The objective is to create a custom action that returns the RTT from any requested domain. In other words I want to tell the assistant to Ping whatever domain and provide me with the RTT or respond that the server isn't reachable. Whereas I'm not ignorant or unable to research and apply results, I've not seen any similar project or a web-hook that would be easily applied. I've got some IFTTT experience and have created Glitch projects that have provided me with additional utility for the assistant. Honestly ''created'' is an overstatement, implementation was just a little step above script-kiddie abilities. The result was that the assistant now provides me with more functionality to control my media center on a Firestick than Amazon's skill does.

So, my assumption is that this is a pretty low level skill.  I have no interest in this being anything other than a personal action. That said, I can handle invocation and all the other overhead necessary for human interface...etc but would surely appreciate assistance, references to similar projects or a helpful overview of what one thinks is the best method to accomplish the task.

If you are reading this and wondering why I posted here, please provide me with a more appropriate or topical forum location.

TIA

Comment: I'm a little confused. Is this something that you've written? Something that you want to write? Something that you've tried and don't know how to finish? StackOverflow works best when you've attempted something, but are having problems doing so - in which case, you should show what you've done and what problems you're having or what you need to do?

Comment: What is the question? Please read [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you are looking specifically to build an Action for media control, you may also want to check out the Smart Home traits for MediaState, Volume Control and Channel - however, these are not designed for individual custom Actions.